# How to run python2.7 supported lib under python 3.5 virtualenv

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, python-3.5

I have created python3.5 virtualenv, but there is python library python-goose(https://github.com/grangier/python-goose) which only runs on python 2.7. 
What could be the possible solutions so that python code can support this library. 
It defies the sole pupose of virtualenv but i need some patch so that my code can run.

Comment: You would need to update the module to support 3.x yourself.

Comment: Or else run 2 different python installations in your virtual environment and only use goose with the 2.7 installation to do whatever work you need to do with it and keep everything else running on 3.x

Comment: library is used by python django server which runs on python3.x virtualenv. Any suggestions  on how to update library to python 3.x

Comment: You would need to update the actual source code. Is it possible to use 2 installations of python for your project and just use the library in 2.7 to do the work it needs to do but keep Django running on 3.x ?

Comment: Yeah, i am using some libraries which are only for python3 so i have to use python 3.x  env now i have to add another lib which runs only on 2.x